# Typescript Flat Object to Nested Tree Object, How to build it with distinct values?

Tags: angular, typescript, object, nested, nested-loops

This is the flat object I'm working with, it has many more results, ~6800. I've been trying to convert it to a nested tree (like the one listed below) for about 13 hours now & I'm truly lost.

```
[
  {
    "make": "Acura",
    "classification": "Mid SUV",
    "segment": "Competitive Trucks",
    "model": "RDX",
    "catalogDetail": "RDX_SUV_4_Gasoline_2013_Base w/Tech_FWD_3.5_6_105.7_Automatic"
  },
  {
    "make": "Acura",
    "classification": "Midsize Car",
    "segment": "Competitive Cars",
    "model": "TSX",
    "catalogDetail": "TSX_Sedan_4_Gasoline_2012_Base w/Tech_FWD_2.4_4_106.4_Automatic"
  },
  {
    "make": "Aston Martin",
    "classification": "Compact Car",
    "segment": "Competitive Cars",
    "model": "DB11",
    "catalogDetail": "DB11_Convertible_2_Gasoline_2019_Volante_RWD_4.0_8_110.4_Automatic"
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is build this flat object into a nested structure like this:

```
[
  {
    "make": [ 
      { "Acura",
        "classification": [{
          "Mid SUV",
          "segment": [{
            "Competitive Trucks",
            "model": [{
              "RDX",
              "catalogDetail": [{
                "RDX_SUV_4_Gasoline_2013_Base w/Tech_FWD_3.5_6_105.7_Automatic"
              }]
            }]
          }],
          "Midsize Car",      
          "segment": [{
            "Competitive Cars",
            "model": [{
              "TSX",
              "catalogDetail": [{
                "TSX_Sedan_4_Gasoline_2012_Base w/Tech_FWD_2.4_4_106.4_Automatic"
              }]
            }]
          }] 
        }],
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "make": [
      { "Aston Martin",
        "classification": [{
          "Compact Car",
          "segment": [{
            "Competitive Cars",
            "model": [{
              "DB11",
              "catalogDetail": [{
                "DB11_Convertible_2_Gasoline_2019_Volante_RWD_4.0_8_110.4_Automatic"
              }]
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Where the structure falls into a nested structure like:
make --> classification --> segment --> model --> catalogdetail.
So there would be multiple car makes, ford, Cadillac, etc.
Multiple classifications, multiple different segments under each make.

This is what I've tried:

```
    this._servicesService.getHierarchy().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
/*      this.data = data;*/
      /*      this.dataStore = data;*/


      let distinctSeg = [...new Set(data.map(x => x.segment))];
      let distinctClass = [...new Set(data.map(x => x.classification))];
      let distinctMod = [...new Set(data.map(x => x.model))];
      let distinctCd = [...new Set(data.map(x => x.catalogDetail))];

     const newData = [];
      data.forEach(e => {
        if (newData.length == 0) {
          newData.push({
            make: e.make,
            segment: e.segment,
            classification: e.classification,
            model: [e.model],
            catalogDetail: [e.catalogDetail]
          });
        } else {
          let foundIndex = newData.findIndex(fi => fi.make === e.make, fi => fi.segment = e.segment);
          if (foundIndex >= 0) {
            /* newData[foundIndex].make.push(e.make),*/
            /* newData[foundIndex].segment.push(e.segment),*/
            /* newData[foundIndex].classification.push(e.classification),*/
            newData[foundIndex].model.push(e.model);
            newData[foundIndex].catalogDetail.push(e.catalogDetail);
          } else {
            newData.push({
              make: e.make,
              segment: distinctSeg,
              classification: distinctClass,
              model: [e.model],
              catalogDetail: [e.catalogDetail]
            });
          }
        }
      });
      console.log(newData);
    })
```

This give me distinct values for model, segment and class, (not model or catalogDetail for some reason) but the nested structure isn't there & i'm truly lost on how to proceed. I've looked at a number of examples on here & I really haven't been successful applying any of the previously listed routes. Any insight or tips would be greatly appreciated. I attached a picture to better visualize the final desired output in case I have the wrong syntax.
[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izjoc.png)

Comment: @jcalz Hey thanks for the feedback! I was putting classification1 & 2 to show that they would be different classifications like 1 would be Mid SUV, 2 would be Midsize Car. Sorry, I realize how unclear that was. There aren't multiple classification keys, just different types of values inside of each of those keys. I'm looking for a nested tree from the 1st example that breaks it down from make being the parent nodes all the way down to catalogdetail being the leaf node. Sorry still very new to coding as a whole & appreciate the help.

Comment: @jcalz added what I believe the final array looks like and a photo just to make it clear in case I have the syntax wrong.

Comment: That syntax is indeed wrong.  If you can't even express the exact output you want, then it's hard to answer.  I could make a guess given your image that you don't actually necessarily need arrays anywhere except for maybe at the leaves, and even then it's not obvious what those values should be... and do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrXaaW).  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer.  If not, then I'd strongly suggest figuring out how to write the output you want in well-formatted JavaScript.  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: gotcha, so you were pretty much on the money, this is the exact output I want, in the commented-out section. https://tsplay.dev/mMB5QW    I wouldn't need the [] on catalogdetail. Sorry about that, will definitely do more research.

Comment: @jcalz for sure, thanks for your help, at least now I know what to learn moving forward!

Comment: @jcalz Very similar, I just dont want all the extra stuff after the catalogDetail, Like so it ends at the display of the strings inside of catalogDetail like: https://tsplay.dev/NVbQZN  if it's not possible like you said though, I can definitely work with this

Comment: I don't get it.  Can't you just write out the exact value you want?  Right now it's an empty array at the end (because you commented out the contents); if you want an empty array [I can give you an empty array](https://tsplay.dev/WoALaN).  Do you want the last value not to be a key but a bare string in an array?  If so [I can give that to you](https://tsplay.dev/mq3Kkw).

Comment: @jcalz The array of strings

Comment: Okay, I wrote up my answer.  You might want to [edit] the question so that the desired output is exactly as I've shown (or I can do it if you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, for input-output, you want something like this:

```
const inp = [
  { a: "x", b: "u", c: "q" }, { a: "x", b: "v", c: "r" },
  { a: "x", b: "u", c: "s" }, { a: "x", b: "v", c: "t" },
  { a: "y", b: "u", c: "q" }, { a: "y", b: "u", c: "r" },
  { a: "y", b: "v", c: "s" },
];

const outp = collect(inp, "a", "b", "c");
console.log(outp);
// {x:{u: ["q","s"], v:["r","t"]}, y:{u:["q","r"], v:["s"]}}
```

where `collect()` is a function that takes an array of objects and a list of keys of those objects.  (It needs to be at least one key, and the input objects should have `string` values at those keys.)  Our job is to implement `collect()`.

---

The approach I take will be recursive; first, the base case, where you call `collect(inp, key1)` for just one key.  In this case, we just want to return an array of the values at the `key1` key, which we can get just by [`map`ping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the input array; i.e., `inp.map(v => v[key1])`.

Then the recursive step: when you call `collect(inp, key1, ...keyRest)` with more than one key, the output will have keys corresponding to the `key1` property of the elements of `inp`.  In the above example, if we call `collect(inp, "a", ...keyRest)`, then the output will have keys `x` and `y`.  For the `x` key, we collect the elements of `inp` whose `a` property is `"x"` into another array `inpX`, and then the value at the `x` key will be `collect(inpX, ...keyRest)`.  And analogously for the `y` key.  That is, we split the input array into sub-arrays corresponding to the values at the `key1` key, and then evaluate `collect(subArr, ...keyRest)` for each subarray.

---

That's a verbal description of the algorithm.  Let's see what it implies for the *typings* for `collect()`:

```
declare function collect<K extends (keyof T)[], T extends object>(
  arr: (T & Record<K[number], string>)[], ...keys: K): Collect<K>;

type Collect<K extends PropertyKey[]> =
  K extends [any] ? string[] :
  K extends [any, ...infer R extends PropertyKey[]] ? { [k: string]: Collect<R> } :
  never;
```

Here we are saying that `collect()` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function that accepts an array of elements of object type `T` and a list of keys of [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) `K`.  We [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `arr` so that each element of the `arr` array is of type `T` and has a `string` property at each key element in the `K` tuple.  And we constrain `K` so that each key element is some key of `T`.

And we return a value of type `Collect<K>`, where `Collect<K>` is itself a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) representing an object with nested `string` [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and whose base case value type is `string[]`.

---

And now for the implementation:

```
function collect(arr: any[], ...keys: string[]) {
  if (!keys.length) throw new Error("need at least one key");
  const [k, ...rest] = keys;

  // base case
  if (!rest.length) return arr.map(v => v[k]);

  // recurse; first collect the sub-arrays for each value at key k
  const subArrays: Record<string, any[]> = {}
  arr.forEach(v => (subArrays[v[k]] ??= []).push(v));

  // then build the return object by calling collect(subArrayVk, ...rest) for each subarray
  const ret: Record<string, any> = {};
  Object.keys(subArrays).forEach(vk => ret[vk] = collect(subArrays[vk], ...rest));
  return ret;
}
```

---

Because the function's call signature returns a generic conditional type, it's easiest to make the function a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) so that the implementation is checked loosely.  That just means we have a declared call signature before the implementation:

```
// call signature
function collect<K extends (keyof T)[], T extends object>(
  arr: (T & Record<K[number], string>)[], ...keys: K): Collect<K>;

// implementation
function collect(arr: any[], ...keys: string[]) {
  // ✂ snip, see above
}
```

---

All right, let's test it out:

```
const outp = collect(inp, "a", "b", "c");
console.log(outp);
// {x:{u: ["q","s"], v:["r","t"]}, y:{u:["q","r"], v:["s"]}}
```

That works!  And your example:

```
const x = collect(arr, "make", "classification", "segment", "model", "catalogDetail");
console.log(x);
/* {
  "Acura": {
    "Mid SUV": {
      "Competitive Trucks": {
        "RDX": [
          "RDX_SUV_4_Gasoline_2013_Base w/Tech_FWD_3.5_6_105.7_Automatic"
        ]
      }
    },
    "Midsize Car": {
      "Competitive Cars": {
        "TSX": [
          "TSX_Sedan_4_Gasoline_2012_Base w/Tech_FWD_2.4_4_106.4_Automatic"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Aston Martin": {
    "Compact Car": {
      "Competitive Cars": {
        "DB11": [
          "DB11_Convertible_2_Gasoline_2019_Volante_RWD_4.0_8_110.4_Automatic"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}   */
```

That also works!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmADjAvDA2gKBjA3jAQwC4YAiAD1IBoYAjE0gV2pmAYEdSYBfG-YspRr0yANxZsyAJy69seQgyF0GzGpNIRZfRYJYjS49Qyjb5-BgE99qiR20KBpa8NvHpZnBbIuVYu2RaPFSYALoA3JigkLAgjFDIaKAANskApsBQABQIiDSkBCyktEXApACUkdEQIOkAdMkgAOZZcQmVmAD0nXjkRLiMJOiknFSapKE0okTDMmOmobwwlv2Dw6OkMpMw08Nai9yYR5hQlohpMADCtemZADwA0jBp5FBpYAAmEDAAClIg5ykpweaUs6FCAD5UPIni83p9vugCGBLKEYAB+GDQKQIJrgmBEGHPV7vL4YZGWGh1akIABmaSkMAASsT4WS-gCGcDQeC0Zj8OgANYkbG40Ika6pDJQO5MqHcAnyMBpUQMyKYWmMMCZODgVg3aWPVmk75ZQWgkC0mAAFXK4Jo1uNCJgIFoACtpRCsvICFIpCQso6AGTMjIgKQfR7oMCMAC2tAZ21FYCaELt22pdXNlggJAe5QlBvuDwh6s12qgurA+qlmSyvv9hBR9pgmezuaxUBxKfB5Tw8jgVqyAEJ2w13k0oAALPvT-4AdxgysXAFE-eGsqRlWkPoRYOkCNAXcqYNmKpEcNVYEKqdSpGloGi0O31ThunRDxdgJ+B0Ph-foHHFNpz7e8oEYKRqwbOpYwIRAslEVAoVEIVQg6eR33vYAIIgNJwhgWk4CkI8UluWBpwuCBGFoABaBsCBzAjw2eAhgCnHYCGSRgLgIWBs1PeQryxaiAEE-QYjsmTDCM7mTJoaApcEoTQXBDhwaDaXDFdWKnBCkJgLIqNoMSpAk9AUMFUI+XRNBezqRBGAgXTRHKdC3x6Cjq1oRg4GSXcKJgMCIOrV0PUyOhLFYTjklxGsyMM0TxMsAA1QVbzqACoD7TTGTSHThNoejLEE8AjzAkgpNAGS5IUlFlLwbgLxgAB5d1pSzUEIAS4ykogco6hy7S2IQwV9LA8zLNQOLpW6kyzNESz0sy1ymqCyDArSKBIkOKJStgBspqwLx5BwUhYPNUgGBE7DTOoE6yGAZJDwgQc4G-StwEusgAFk4F3ABlABVZK7pwU7cKaWN3lMBhrljc5K0rVUbSkRhgEFLQQjBshYxAD40mSL7SCZAARAANUGwdId7OOaEnNoIXyidJsmAH0geS1mABZWYAcUPWoEDSVmACYAAYAEYAGZWYAIU-GB506a0MinVmADEAHUSdZqW6gAVlZgA2VmJbF-W6gAdlZkT4hAWDKzKeQ5GO7GzoIC6rpuwosapx7nte96qyJ36vjgAAvC5Ll9SnwbSSHoaJuGEbgJGo99TH7rOvGCaJ61-op33TppxomnpqBGcJhh87Z-6d2Rbm+YFmLlVFyWRblhWlZVtiNe10W6h5nmzaNwebbth23tIZ3fdwLPzrSImROgPVvt9SswFjh6nogF7CKDz7YftxBWNgaO5iziGobAGGyGTzbU7gZHz8zt3cfxquyBJ2WJYlrfqd4rTMuDMmYMG-r-Vm1wwCqiBHAWg6RRZNxqC3YW4sJYAE5WbJVqMiN4rMmT9y5nUMWrMAAcpszZj1tlAe2vEp7OzCEcIS5ApqkRmg2fIC9Sg7z3m9Ohn18hX0TpwnOhN8glzpiAwmHRqi1DSA0ZoWRyAdE6AAKn7Kda6EFCgkDnm7UOMAOZfT0djO+x8H5pxRmjDGxj7puxZl9I6pj7Hk3ZsDRu-NkFCzbtLTuuFFbK1Vn3HWetDYmzNhba21DaGO2ns4nAoQ7E8Hui7KmocXqRyuDHXRSTSD30Rk-dOxFbHxLIDXRxSS3Y13ZvXMAHjm7eLQR3eW-ju5BK1jrEWY9h5i1HjzaJk8nalMSc4tSYMxmpNIMvGh1Y16wM3jkt2ydT5ZJkIs0xeTzEFOfhnEp8TSDgL-kMSpVNDmQPADAys8DUFIMFq3NBmDsFPRvsLAhOsiEkPIb-MWVCJ50KGfEkZpixk4AmZgBUOBVGdCAA)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method for this.

This method allows you to easily convert a js array to an object.

You can do something like the following:

```
arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue)=>{
  if(!accumulator[currentValue.make]){
    accumulator[currentValue.make] = []
  }
  accumulator[currentValue.make][0] = {...<PUT YOUR OBJECT VALUE HERE>}
},{})
```

Answer (score 0):

As Avrham say, you can use reduce. Imagine you create a function like

```
  reduce(data:any[],key:string,keyArray:string)
  {
    return data.reduce((a:any[],b:any)=>{
       const element=a.find(x=>x[key]==b[key])
       const value=b[key]
       delete b[key]
       if (!element)
          a.push({[key]:value,[keyArray]:[b]})
       else
          element[keyArray].push(b)
        return a;
    },[])
  }
}
```

You can use in the way:

```
 const data=this.reduce(this.data,"make","classification")
 data.forEach(x=>{
   x.classification=this.reduce(x.classification,"classification","segment")
   x.classification.forEach(c=>{
    c.segment=this.reduce(c.segment,"segment","model")
    c.segment.forEach(m=>{
       m.model=this.reduce(m.model,"model","catalogDetail")
       m.model.forEach(d=>d.catalogDetail=d.catalogDetail.map(e=>e.catalogDetail))
    })
   })
 })
 this.dataFormatted=data
```

But I think that it's not easy mannage this specie of tree-view. In general you has a tree-view and all the arrays are "children". So I suggest create a function

```
  reduceChildren(data:any[],key:string)
  {
    return data.reduce((a:any[],b:any)=>{
      const element=a.find(x=>x[key]==b[key])
      const value=b[key]
      delete b[key]
      if (!element)
         a.push({[key]:value,children:[b]})
      else
         element.children.push(b)
       return a;
   },[])
  }
```

You can use like

```
 const data=this.reduceChildren(this.data,"make")
 data.forEach(x=>{
   x.children=this.reduceChildren(x.children,"classification")
   x.children.forEach(c=>{
    c.children=this.reduceChildren(c.children,"segment")
    c.children.forEach(m=>{
       m.children=this.reduceChildren(m.children,"model")
       m.children.forEach(d=>d.children=d.children.map(e=>e.catalogDetail))
    })
   })
 })
 this.dataFormatted=data
```

You can see the two approach in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-an4ski?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, will look into this. Ya'll are great